# .net core 3.1 post ajax list of objects to MVC controller no data arriving

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to post a list of objects to a MVC controller via AJAX, but when it gets to the controller the `editedPrices` parameter is 0.

What am I doing wrong? Currently I'm not sure if the issue is with the data I'm sending or the controller.

Java Script:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newPrices = [
        { "id": "1", "wePrice" : "99", "wdPrice":"79" },
        { "id": "2", "wePrice" :"89", "wdPrice":"59" }
    ];
    editedPrices = JSON.stringify(newPrices);
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("EditRates")",
        data: {editedPrices : newPrices},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

c# object

```cs
public class EditPrices
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string wePrice { get; set; }
    public string wdPrice { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
public int EditRates(List<EditPrices> editedPrices )
{
    return editedPrices.Count();
}
```

I've tried using the `[FromBody]` attribute, but then the editedPrices parameter is null (as opposed to showing a count of 0).

**Edit**
Just to clarify, I can see that some data is being sent in the AJAX request. And I can see that the controller is being called. So the AJAX request it self is working. But I'm either sending the data in the 'wrong' format, or there's something wrong with how I'm trying to receive it.

Comment: Please open the dev tools for your browser and look at the Console page.

Comment: I've got that open, but it's blank (no errors or warnings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just change this line:

```
...
data: JSON.stringify(newPrices),
...
```

- You are making another object with `{editedPrices : newPrices}`. Your API accepting array.